# example code for colorpicker in phonegap

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I cant fix colorpicker.js in phonegap, it is not working! Some help, please?

thanks

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
                    color: '#0000ff',
                    onShow: function (colpkr) {
                        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                        return false;
                    },
                    onHide: function (colpkr) {
                        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                        return false;
                    },
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {

                        //$('body').css('background', '#' + hex);
                        $("#hex_color").val('#'+hex);

                    }
                });
    var html ='<div id="texto">';
                        html +='<input id="newtext" type="text" value="Hello!">';

                        //html +='<input id="change" type="color" value="#ff0667" data-text="hidden" style="height:20px;width:20px;" />';

                        html += '<input type="text" id="hex_color">';
                        html += '<div id="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>';

                        html +='<button id="addbutton">Add this text</button>';
                        html +='</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Spectrum Colorpicker](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). This is very nice color picker plugin.

Download the zip file and include the `spectrum.js` file and `spectrum.css` file to your page. Then you have to create a text box as follows

```
<input type='color' id='custom' />
```

Inside your script file

```
 $("#custom").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
 });
```

Hope it helped you

Comment: I try but I cant do it!

Comment: Yes, "Spectrum.js" was not worked for me on phonegap app.

Answer (score 0):

There one paid color picker  [JQuery Mobile Color Picker](http://mobiscroll.com/component/colorpicker), only use it if you don't find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the 
Angular-JS directive **[ngjs-color-picker](http://simeg.github.io/ngjs-color-picker)**

A small directive which essentially is a color picker but with a few extra functions - for *Angular-JS*. Suitable for developing custom color pallet in phonegap / Cordova apps.