# Android Webview with Colorpicker Eyecon

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, eyecon-plugin

I implemented the colorpicker in one android app .. but to select the color you must click because the webview does not accept the click and drag, how can I change the functions to work the touch of webview, I tried to replace the "mousemove" by "mouseover "but no sucess

I think this is part of the code should I change

```
  downSelector = function (ev) {
            var current = {
                cal: $(this).parent(),
                pos: $(this).offset()
            };
            current.preview = current.cal.data('colorpicker').livePreview;
            $(document).bind('mouseup', current, upSelector);
            $(document).bind('mousemove', current, moveSelector);
        },

        moveSelector = function (ev) {
change.apply(
ev.data.cal.data('colorpicker').fields.eq(6)
.val(parseInt(100*(150 - Math.max(0,Math.min(150,(ev.pageY - ev.data.pos.top))))/150, 10))
.end().eq(5).val(parseInt(100*(Math.max(0,Math.min(150,(ev.pageX - ev.data.pos.left))))/150, 10))
.get(0),[ev.data.preview]
);
return false;
 },

 upSelector = function (ev) {

  moveSelector(ev);

 fillRGBFields(ev.data.cal.data('colorpicker').color, ev.data.cal.get(0));
 fillHexFields(ev.data.cal.data('colorpicker').color, ev.data.cal.get(0));
 $(document).unbind('mouseup', upSelector);
 $(document).unbind('mousemove', moveSelector);
 return false;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a Try with SO [**example code for colorpicker in phonegap**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716865/example-code-for-colorpicker-in-phonegap).

Also this things may help [javascript-color-picker](http://cssgallery.info/javascript-color-picker/) or [spectrum](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) (not sure).

You can also call native activity java codes from webview and get back the picked colors from native libs! The native color picker dialog pop ups like this

Update:

**https://github.com/Gautier/jquery-colorpicker-mobile** (Github) (fork of http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ with touch events support

[jqm color picker](http://mobiscroll.com/component/colorpicker) (paid)

[image]

Comment: thanks bro, but i got the whole thing done in the eyecon plugin
but it is a great idea indeed ! i'll keep searching! thanks again